# Extract Values from a database within a period of time.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, moodle, timespan

I have a MOODLE in my web server. I want to track the usage of the said resource on a weekly and monthly basis. The usage will be based on the sum reads and writes of the users. I will get the data from the `mdl_stats_user_daily` table of my MOODLE database.

I want to give some acknowledgement and token to those who will make it to the top 10. I have an existing php script connecting to the database and performing a query to get my results but it seems that my query is wrong. Here is my query:

```
$query = "SELECT user.firstname, user.lastname, user.userid, stats.userid, stats.roleid, 
          SUM( statsreads ) AS numreads, SUM( statswrites ) AS numwrites, 
          SUM( statsreads ) + SUM( statswrites ) AS totalactivity 
          FROM  `mdl_stats_user_daily` stats, `mdl_user` user 
          WHERE userid IN (SELECT userid 
                           FROM mdl_role_assignments 
                           WHERE roleid IN (1,2,3,4)) 
          AND user.id = stats.userid 
          AND stats.timeend < ".(time() - 604800)." 
          GROUP BY userid ORDER BY totalactivity DESC Limit 20";
```

You can see there the line:

```
 Where userid IN (SELECT userid 
                    FROM mdl_role_assignments 
                   WHERE roleid IN (1,2,3,4)) 
                     AND user.id = stats.userid 
                     AND stats.timeend < ".(time() - 604800)".
```

The `".(time() - 604800)"` is the line I am using to filter the results, just getting the usage one week in the past. The "604800" is the number of seconds in one week or 7 days. But it seems that I am wrong, even if I change the number, my query keeps on returning same results. Can someone help me?

Comment: To get the results of last week should it not be `AND stats.timeend > ".(time() - 604800)"`?

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, rather the code you suggest returns an empty set.

Comment: Don't hardcode the tablenames in Moodle. Instead of `mdl_user` use `{user}`. You should also look into api for limit and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this query:-

```
SELECT user.firstname, user.lastname, user.userid, stats.userid, stats.roleid, 
      SUM( statsreads ) AS numreads, SUM( statswrites ) AS numwrites, 
      SUM( statsreads ) + SUM( statswrites ) AS totalactivity 
      FROM  `mdl_stats_user_daily` stats, `mdl_user` user 
      WHERE userid IN (SELECT userid 
                       FROM mdl_role_assignments 
                       WHERE roleid IN (1,2,3,4)) 
      AND user.id = stats.userid 
      AND stats.timeend < ADDDATE(CURDATE(), -7)
      GROUP BY userid ORDER BY totalactivity DESC Limit 20"
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: thank you but MySQL did not run the query, rather it returned and error.

Comment: You can try it now without the select keyword in and condition.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and it gives me some output but even if I change  7 into any number, it will give me same result.

Comment: should I used the "BETWEEN" clause?

Comment: I Used 7 only for past week date. if you want more back date then you can use that digit such as 30 for previous month and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As EricBouwers said it is > rather than <

But also you should use the role name instead of the role id as the id may change.

Also EXISTS rather than IN is better for performance.

```
SELECT user.id,
       user.firstname,
       user.lastname,
       SUM(statsreads) AS numreads,
       SUM(statswrites) AS numwrites, 
       SUM(statsreads) + SUM(statswrites) AS totalactivity 
FROM mdl_stats_user_daily stats
JOIN mdl_user user ON user.id = stats.userid
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ra.userid
              FROM mdl_role_assignments ra
              JOIN mdl_role r ON r.id = ra.roleid AND r.shortname IN ('student')
              WHERE ra.userid = user.id)
AND stats.timeend > NOW() - (7*24*60*60)
GROUP BY user.id, user.firstname, user.lastname
ORDER BY totalactivity DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: thank you, but it MySQL gives me same ouput even if I change the filter, I mean the number (7*24*60*60).

Answer (score 0):

With your help and the others, I was able to figure out the correct query to get my desired output. Thank you so much. Here is my final query for my weekly report:

```
$query = "SELECT user.firstname, user.lastname, stats.userid, stats.roleid, 
          SUM( statsreads ) AS numreads, SUM( statswrites ) AS numwrites, 
          SUM( statsreads ) + SUM( statswrites ) AS totalactivity 
          FROM `mdl_stats_user_daily` stats, `mdl_user` user 
          WHERE userid IN (SELECT userid 
                           FROM mdl_role_assignments 
                           WHERE roleid IN (1,2,3,4)) 
          AND user.id = stats.userid 
          AND WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(stats.timeend)) = (WEEK(CURDATE())-1)  
          GROUP BY userid ORDER BY totalactivity DESC";
```

Then here's for the monthly report:

```
$query = "SELECT user.firstname, user.lastname, stats.userid, stats.roleid, 
          SUM( statsreads ) AS numreads, SUM( statswrites ) AS numwrites, 
          SUM( statsreads ) + SUM( statswrites ) AS totalactivity 
          FROM `mdl_stats_user_daily` stats, `mdl_user` user 
          WHERE userid IN (SELECT userid 
                           FROM mdl_role_assignments 
                           WHERE roleid IN (1,2,3,4)) 
          AND user.id = stats.userid 
          AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(stats.timeend)) = (MONTH(CURDATE())-1)  
          GROUP BY userid 
          ORDER BY totalactivity DESC";
```

Hope this can help the future users.